Generate a Client assertion and access token for Sharepoint Rest Api
I have trying to get client assertion and access token to access Admin site via SharePoint Rest Api using App only permission. I can achieve it easily in C# using COSM. So in java is there any library or is they possible way to do this?
is there any way to generate access token to access the admin site using app only (using Client assertion). Or Is there any similar library in java to achive it.
